# Sports schedule not showing string

Tags: java

It's a program that is a sports league, a group of teams plays through a Schedule of Games and determine the winner.

The program runs fine to the point where the final output won't let me see the winner, it shows this instead:

> The season winner(s) with 9 points: [Ljava.lang.String;@e73f9ac

I changed it to `teams.length` which made the program work but it would show me the teams (`i`) number instead of the string name like "Vancouver".

Thanks in advance.

```
    }

    int peak = 0;                                
    int[] total = new int[teams.length];         

    for (int i=0; i<teams.length; i++){                    
      total[i] = 2*wins[i]+ties[i]; 
      if (total[i] > peak) peak = total[i];

      System.out.println(teams[i]+" - " + wins[i] + " wins, " + losses[i] + " losses, " + ties[i] + " ties = " + total[i]);
  }    

  System.out.println("The season winner(s) with " + peak + " points: " + teams);  

  for (int i=0; i<teams.length; i++){
    if (peak < total[i]) peak = total[i];
  }      

}

static int indexOfTeam(String team, String[] teams){  
  for (int i=0; i<teams.length; i++)
    if (team.compareTo(teams[i]) == 0) return i;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the winning team you're printing the `teams` array.  
While iterating store besides the peak, the index of the winning team:

```
 int index = -1;
 for (int i=0; i<teams.length; i++){                    
     total[i] = 2*wins[i]+ties[i]; 
     if (total[i] > peak) {
        index = i;
        peak = total[i];
     }
     System.out.println(teams[i]+" - " + wins[i] + " wins, " + losses[i] + " 
   losses, " + ties[i] + " ties = " + total[i]);
 }
```

and finally:

```
System.out.println("The season winner(s) with " + peak + " points: " + 
 teams[index]);
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it gives me index in error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: nvm your a legend

Comment: im just dumb haha

Answer (score 0):

teams is an array of Strings, you must insert the index after the name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all teams use [Arrays.toString(teams)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])), but I think that you would like to print only part of teams array, so you can create list of winners

```
 List<String> winners = new ArrayList<Integer>;
 for (int i=0; i<teams.length; i++){                    
     total[i] = 2*wins[i]+ties[i]; 
     if (total[i] > peak) {
        winners.add(teams[i]);
        peak = total[i];
     }
 System.out.println(teams[i]+" - " + wins[i] + " wins, " + losses[i] + " 
  losses, " + ties[i] + " ties = " + total[i]);
}
```

indexes object you can simply print

```
System.out.println("The season winner(s) with " + peak + " points: " +winners);
```

If you want to have an array you can use [toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) on winners object.